# Angularjs: Testing controller function, which changes $scope

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test this controller function:

```
$scope.deleteAccount = function(account) {

  Account.deleteAccount(account._id)
  .then(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(a, i) {
      if (a === account) {
        $scope.accounts.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    $scope.errors.other = err.message;
  });
};
```

It is on a admin page. The function calls the factory (with promise) and the factory deletes the Account on the server. Then the function removes the element in the scope so that the deleted element isn't shown again.

My test looks like that:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$httpBackend_) {

    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $location = _$location_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    fakeResponse = '';

    AdminAccountCtrl = $controller('AdminAccountCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
    $location.path('/admin/account');
}));

it('test delete account', function () {
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/admin/account');

    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/accounts').respond([{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 3}]);
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'app/admin/admin.account.html').respond(fakeResponse);
    $httpBackend.when('DELETE', '/api/accounts/1').respond(fakeResponse);
    $httpBackend.flush();

    $scope.deleteAccount($scope.accounts[0]);
    expect($scope.accounts).toEqual([{_id: 2}, {_id: 3}]);
});
```

Sadly the result is:

```
Expected [ { _id : 1 }, { _id : 2 }, { _id : 3 } ] to equal [ { _id : 2 }, { _id : 3 } ].
```

Comment: And... what is your question ?

Comment: The first element isn't removed - the test fails.
I want to know why the array hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling `$scope.$digest()` after `deleteAccount`. This is needed because tests don't have digest cycles the same way it runs normally in the browser.

```
$scope.deleteAccount($scope.accounts[0]);
$scope.$digest();
expect($scope.accounts).toEqual([{_id: 2}, {_id: 3}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm afraid it didn't work. I also tried to spyOn the function and $scope.$apply() but the error remains.

Comment: maybe you also need to move `$httpBackend.flush()` to run just after `deleteAccount`

Comment: moving the flush didn't work account was undefined. But calling flush a second time after deleteAccount worked. So thank you very much.
```
 ...
    $httpBackend.when('DELETE', '/api/accounts/1').respond(fakeResponse);
    $httpBackend.flush();

    $scope.deleteAccount($scope.accounts[0]);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    ...
```